# Deedle Frame.Rows |> Series.windowWhile |> new frame with a new column computed from the windows?

Tags: f#, deedle

I am trying to use the Series.windowWhile function to window over rows of a Deedle frame. I want to calculate some statistics based on the window and then add the statistic back to the row.

The below code does not work once I get to the point of the `last.Merge(length)` line but it hopefully illustrates my goal:

```
type Person = 
  { Name:string; Age:int; Countries:string list; }

let peopleRecds = 
  [ { Name = "Joe"; Age = 51; Countries = [ "UK"; "US"; "UK"] }
    { Name = "Tomas"; Age = 28; Countries = [ "CZ"; "UK"; "US"; "CZ" ] }
    { Name = "Eve"; Age = 2; Countries = [ "FR" ] }
    { Name = "Suzanne"; Age = 15; Countries = [ "US" ] } ]
// Turn the list of records into data frame 
let peopleList = Frame.ofRecords peopleRecds
// Use the 'Name' column as a key (of type string)
let people = peopleList |> Frame.indexRowsInt "Age" |> Frame.sortRowsByKey
let newPeople =
    people.Rows
    |> Series.windowWhile (fun k1 k2 -> abs (k1 - k2) < 14)
    |> Series.mapValues (fun v ->
        let length = series ["length" => (v |> Series.values |> Seq.length)]
        let last = v |> Series.takeLast 1
        let newLast = last.Merge(length)
        newLast)
    |> Frame.ofRows
```

I want `newPeople` to be the `people` frame with a new column called `length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that `v` is an `ObjectSeries<string>` if all you need is to add the calculated length from your `mapValues` you can do it this way:

```
let newPeople' =
    people.Rows
    |> Series.windowWhile (fun k1 k2 -> abs (k1 - k2) < 14)
    |> Series.mapValues (fun v ->
        series ["length" => (v |> Series.values |> Seq.length)]    
    )
    |> Frame.ofRows

people.Merge(newPeople')
```

Comment: @nh2, instead `Series.mapValues (fun v ->series ["length" => (v |> Series.values |> Seq.length)])`
can: `Series.mapValues (fun v -> series ["length" => v.ValueCount])`
or with functional style `Series.mapValues (fun v -> series ["length" => (v |> Series.countValues)])`